# Do zsh aliases lower terminal performance?

Tags: terminal, zsh, alias

I really make use of aliases and I've started to create some function aliases which are made of only one `if..else` case. For instance, I have the following alias to start my `json-server`:

```bsh
jsp() {                                                           
        if [[ -z $2 ]]; then                                      
                json-server --watch data/db.json --port $1
        else                                            
                json-server --watch $1 --port $2        
        fi                          
}
```

Does having a lot of aliases effect the terminal performance? Can this `if..else` type of aliases be improved in some kind of way (e.g., making them single line)?

Comment: That's a function, not an alias. Also, you're asking about Bash, but have tagged the question with Zsh. What kind of a performance effect do you think there might be, apart from making it faster for you to type often-used commands?

Comment: Was just wondering whether having really big alias/functions files would make the terminal take more time to load or to run whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having many aliases and small functions will not have any measurable runtime performance impact.

Having many *large* functions will impact the time it take to start an interactive shell. The shell has to parse all the code. You aren't likely to notice it unless your init files are on a slow network filesystem. If this is a problem (and once again, don't even worry about it unless it's actually a problem), make sure your large functions are autoloaded and byte-compiled (for zsh), or split them out into separate scripts (for any shell, and that's usually a good idea for any large function anyway, so that it can be used on its own without first loading an interactive shell).

As a point of comparison, if you're using bash's smart completion, it loads about 60k lines of code when bash starts. So to make a visible difference in the startup time, you'd have to have about that much code of your own.